# If statement check if post is set

Tags: php

Hello I'm having some problem.

I want it to be checked by default, and if you unselect it and press submit I want it to be unchecked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="show_signature" value="1"<?php echo isset($_POST['show_signature'])) ? ' checked=""' : '' ?>>
```

This works good unchecking > submitting and checkbox is unchecked and same if you check it and  send the form, it stays checked.

But, I want it to be checked by default. Should'nt this work?

```
if (isset($_POST['show_signature'])) {
    echo ' checked=""';
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

Tried this to

```
if (isset($_POST['show_signature']) || !isset($_POST['show_signature'])) {
    echo ' checked=""';
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

Comment: your gonna need to post more code, the code you have there looks fine, you diont need the second echo though

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['show_signature']) || !isset($_POST['show_signature'])) {` will return true for both checked and unchecked

Comment: Yes it will so hes not echoing it in the correct place, Need more code

Comment: @DevZer0 yeah i noticed that :/

Comment: @user1281385 why do you need more code? this is the only code you need

Comment: The surrounding code is what your are eching to. Your echo is in the wrong place or something is stoping that block being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay; from the question, I got this process 
When the page loads the first time, you want the checkbox to be checked. 
When the page is submitted, if the checkbox is unchecked, let it remain unchecked; otherwise, let it be checked. 
 
Try

```
 
  /*making the assumption that the submission process starts when a submit button 
   with name **submit** is present, use this

*/ 
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    value = '<input type="checkbox" name="show_signature"'; 
    value .= (isset($_POST["show_signature"]))? 'checked="checked"': "";
    value .= ' />';
    print value;
 }
else{ //when the page is initially loaded
 print '<input type="checkbox" name="show_signature" checked="checked" />';
}
```

The reason the post depends on the submit button (or any other field)t is because if the user unchecks the box, the $_POST["show_signature"] variable will not be found, and the form will not be processed at all.
That should resolve the issue. 
 
Hope the explanation is clear and this helps.

Comment: that does work but the problem is I want it to be checked by default

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="show_signature" value="1" `<?php echo isset($_POST['show_signature'])) ? '' : 'checked="checked"' ?> `

Comment: that does make it checked by default de_nuit but even if you dont uncheck the checkbox it gets unchecked on post